# Vlc not installing

Tags: software-installation

on installing vlc i get this error message "Fail to fetch size mismatch" what could be the problem as we are not able to install vlc, gimp or any software even after installing synaptic package manager successfully. The software works fine only for 24 hours and then it gives the above message. Please help...urgently, thanks

Comment: Interesting problem, let me make a question: with "only for 24 hours" you intend a precise amount of time or a session of work concluded with a reboot/shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved [here (bubblenet.be user)](http://bubblenet.be/blog/howto-fix-failed-to-fetch-http-xxx_i386.deb-size-mismatch) by executing in a terminal (press CTRL+ALT+T, also xTerm is fine):

```
sudo aptitude clean
sudo aptitude update
```

Please, since this is an uncommon and interesting problem, feel free to comment under here if you need more help and don't forget to press the UP arrow on the left if I'm of any help.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Open this link : http://www.chip.de/downloads/VLC-media-player-fuer-Linux_36673620.html **Problem solved** :) !!!

Answer (score 0):

The `Failed to fetch [package url] size mismatch` error means that the downloaded package and the server package are different.

There is a chance your problem is due to a network restriction.

1. Open a terminal (`Ctrl + Alt + T`)
2. Run this command and enter your password: `sudo apt-get install vlc`
3. Check the content of the partial downloaded package with this command: `cat /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/vlc-*`

If it has the form of an html page, it means that's the case.